# Have Focus on one JTextField and perform an action related to it

Tags: java, swing

My Application has two JTextField's and one JButton.

I want a code snippet where in

- If the first TextField is focussed/selected, the button will set its TextField (using setText method) to 1,
- If the second TextField is focussed/selected, the button will set its TextField (using setText method) to 1

EDIT : **What I am trying to do** (numInput , denInput are both JTextFields)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String s = e.getActionCommand();                            
        if (numInput.isFocusOwner()) {
            if (s.equals("1")) {
                if (z == 0) {
                    numInput.setText(numInput.getText() + "1");
                } else {
                    numInput.setText("");
                    numInput.setText(numInput.getText() + "1");
                    z = 0;
                }
        }
        else if (denInput.isFocusOwner()) {
            if (s.equals("1")) {
                if (z == 0) {
                    denInput.setText(numInput.getText() + "1");
                } else {
                    denInput.setText("");
                    denInput.setText(numInput.getText() + "1");
                    z = 0;
                }
        }
}
```

This never works for me.

Comment: Use a [FocusListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) to listen for focus changes of the JTextField and act accordingly. For better help sooner, post an [mcve]

Comment: Hey there, I am just out of ideas. Can you please provide a code snippet?

Comment: `Can you please provide a code snippet` You first. See the links I posted in my comment above.

Comment: Yeah, I added the code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `Action` that extends `TextAction` and add this `Action` to your button.

`TextAction` has a `getFocusedComponent()` method that will return the last text component that had focus.

The basic code for the Action would be:

```
TextAction action = new TextAction("")
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
            JTextComponent textField = getFocusedComponent();
            System.out.println( textField.getText() );
    }
};
```

This will only work if you only have two text field on the form. If you have more than two then you would need to add extra code to verify that focus was on either of the two text fields before the button was clicked.